# Test Project.exe has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, memory, breakpoints

When I run the code, it gives me an error that I have triggered a break point.  It doesn't tell me where this break point is.  Can anyone assist?

```
void memLeak()
{
    int *p = new int;
    char * string1 = new char[20];
    char * string2 = new char[25];
    strcpy(string1, "Sheldon");
    string2 = string1;
    delete string2;
    delete string1;
    delete p;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    memLeak();
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When you use `new`, use `delete`.
- When you use `new[]`, use `delete[]`.

I.e., there are separate versions of both for arrays.

```
delete[] string2;
delete[] string1;
delete p;
```

- When you assign `string2 = string1`, you are losing the original pointer to the second string, and trying to delete the first one twice. It is likely this double-delete that is causing the breakpoint error.

---

But better yet, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), and don't worry about using `new`/`delete` directly yourself.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I used the delete[] but still getting a break point error.  One thing I noticed is that if I comment out the string2 = string1;, the break point error is gone.  Am I using the string2 = string1 wrong?

Comment: I see it.  Thank you.  I removed the delete[] string1 and that fixed it.  Thank you.

Comment: @brisk172 You need to understand that removing `delete[] string1` *hides* the problem, but doesn't *fix* it, because you are now leaking one of the original `char` arrays. It is so easy to get this stuff wrong, which is precisely why you shouldn't use naked `new`/`delete`. Use standard components that handle this stuff for you `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc.